# User memory limit exceeded when applying iterative procedure to am image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, memoryerror

Please help me understand earth engine memory usage. I am trying to apply an iterative procedure to a collection of images and then combine these images on a per-pixel basis. Here is the code structure that I am using:

```
var step = function(iteration, list) {
  
  var h0 = ee.Image(ee.List(list).get(-1));
  var h = h0.resample('bilinear').unmask(999);
  ...
  manipulations with h, involving several temporary variables being created
  ...
  return ee.List(list).replace(h0,h); // make sure not grow the list with intermediate steps
};

var iterate = function(h0) {
  var first = ee.List([h0]);
  var seq = ee.List.sequence(1,40);
  var tmp = ee.List(seq.iterate(step,first));
  return ee.Image(tmp.get(-1));
};

var G12 = imageCollection.filterMetadata('grid_id',"equals",12); //collection of uploaded images
var R12 = G12.map(iterate); // filtered collection: 99 images
var h1 = R12.toArray().arraySort().arrayPad([99,1]).arrayGet([90,0]);
```

So, function "step" defines one step of an iterative procedure. Having an old school coding background, I would assume that temporary variables created within the function are being pushed into the stack and then poped after the function has been executed (no memory is wasted). The list variable that is being passed in and out of the function does not grow, I merely replace the last element in the list. Function "iterate" creates a temporary list and maps the "step" function over it in iterative manner (each step using the result of the previous step). It takes an image as the input and spits out a processed (iterated) version of the image. The function was tested and works as intended.
Now I am trying to map it over an image collection. The result is being reduced to a single image via per-pixel sorting procedure. Now, I know, converting an image collection into an array is a memory hog, but I do not see any other way of doing this. More importantly, the last line calculation (reduction) works fine if the number of iterations in "iterate" function is below 40. Once it gets above 40 I get "user memory limit exceeded" error. This tells me that the iterative process adds to memory usage with each iteration, which I would not expect in a traditional code. Is my interpretation correct? Is there any way to code this differently?

Comment: Two thoughts: First, it's not clear to me why you are using a `List` in your iteration at all. It looks like it is always a one-element list, so you might as well pass the image `h0` as your iteration value directly rather than wrapping it in a list. That shouldn't make a large difference, but it's cleaner. Second, in order to understand what the problem might be with the iteration, we'll need to see what your actual "manipulations with h" are — in nearly any troubleshooting, it's worthwhile for you to work on providing a **runnable**, yet simple, script that **demonstrates the problem.**

Comment: As far as List goes, I was just following the example in the guide section, didn't realize that the iterate function can take a regular image instead, thanks for letting me know, I'll modify accordingly. As for providing the entire working code, I did not want people here going through 10s of lines of someone else's code that is not relevant. I assumed the code structure itself is the problem ( I am only starting with earthengine and assumed that I am doing something stupid). It sounds like I am not? If so I'll work on cleaning up the code to make it executable...

Comment: Yes, the iterated result can be *any* value, not just a list. Besides the list wrapper, all you've got is "doing an iterated operation on an image", so if that were the problem then `iterate` would hardly work at all, so we need to see what the operation actually is to see how to diagnose or improve it. Also, there might be a way to do what you want without using `iterate` at all.